# something is terribly wrong with pkg-config

Tags: fedora, pkg-config

I've been having a harrowing time lately just trying to get several C programs compiled because I can't find where the libraries are located and pkg-config seems to be out of order.

I installed GNU GSL like this:

```
wget ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gsl/gsl-1.15.tar.gz
tar xvzf gsl-*gz
cd gsl-1.15
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Apparently it installed in `/usr/local/lib` which is a non-standard place? (1) What is a standard place? (2) How would I get it to install there?

And I can't manage to compile a simple program that uses this library:

```
$ gcc gsl_erf.c -o gsl -I/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib
/tmp/cc3WD9Zq.o: In function `main':
gsl_erf.c:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `gsl_cdf_gaussian_P'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Now, with pkg-config :

```
pkg-config --libs --cflags gslPackage gsl was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gsl.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gsl' found
```

So I did add the directory:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
```

But no luck yet! :( pkg-config still gives me the same message as above. (`Perhaps you sh ...`)

This is a more general problem I face regularly when I have to compile some C program. I would love a general solution for:

1. Where and how do I install my C libs? (Perhaps the same place yum installs them?)
2. How do I correct/configure and use pkg-config

---

**Update** : I tried one of the answer's suggestions below and running the compiled program gives me this : `./gsl_app: error while loading shared libraries: libgsl.so.0: cannot open shared object`

Comment: Just curious ... Why isn't 'yum install gsl' sufficient?

Comment: @rickhg12hs I was reading `21st Century C` and this was one of the exercises. But I want to get this to work this way because I've run into this problem a few times now when trying to get some c library from github that's not in the yum repository.

Comment: Makes sense.  There is a learning curve.  Good luck!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Apparently it installed in /usr/local/lib which is a non-standard place?

It's a standard place, but sometimes systems are configured presuming that you are not going to build-install anything, and so it is left out of the linker cache path.

> Where and how do I install my C libs? (Perhaps the same place yum installs them?)

That is generally a bad idea, esp. if there are potentially distro packages -- now, or down the line -- that conflict.  Stick with /usr/local.

Check to see if `/usr/local/lib` is in ld.so.cache by running `ldconfig -v 2>&1 | grep /usr/local`.  If you don't get any output, create a file `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/local.conf` with one line:

```
/usr/local/lib
```

Run that `ldconfig` line again and this time you should see it.  *You need to run **ldconfig** every time you build and install a library from source*.

> I can't manage to compile a simple program that uses this library

Because you have to pass the `pkg-config` parameters to the compiler.  First, you need to find the actual `gsl.pc`.

```
find /usr/local -name gsl.pc
```

I think it is more likely in `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`, and not `/usr/local/pkgconfig` as you say.  Try `pkg-config --list-all | grep gsl` and see if it's found.  If not `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH` (or whatever the directory with gsl.pc is) and try again.  When you get that right, you may want to add it somewhere in, e.g., `/etc/profile.d`.

Now, to actually compile:

```
gcc gsl_erf.c -o gsl `pkg-config --libs --cflags gsl`
```

You don't need to include `-I` and `-L` yourself; that's what `pkg-config` is for, although all you were likely missing before was `-lgsl`.

Comment: Thanks very much goldilocks! Your assumptions were correct. **however** while pkg-config spits the correct output I get this: `$ gcc gsl_erf.c -o gsl_app \`pkg-config --libs --cflags gsl\` $./gsl_app 
./gsl_app: error while loading shared libraries: libgsl.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: Any clues or ideas?

Comment: I notice you do need to use `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`; `pkg-config` must fork because without the **`export`** it won't find anything in the alternate path.  You need to do that in the same shell you are compiling from, unless you put it in a `.profile` *and log out and in again completely*.

Comment: @gideon what's the output of `pkg-config --libs --cflags gsl`? do you have a `libgsl.so.0`?

Comment: @umläute ok, so only if I do the `export` line then it works. This is my output : `$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH
$ pkg-config --libs --cflags gsl OUTPUT: -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm`

Comment: @umläute I do have a `libgsl.so.0` under `/usr/local/lib`. OK! I just tried compiling my program again and it worked. So yes I need to be in the same shell. However, I need to understand what is going on here? What is `ldconfig` and why can't pkg-config know where my gsl lib is?

Comment: See `man ldconfig`; ld.so is the linux [dynamic linker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker).  `pkg-config` is a little obtuse and AFAIK *the only* way to configure its search path is via `$PKG_CONFIG_PATH` (or during the building of pkg-config itself, I guess).  Which is not so confusing since the shell is the same WRT `$PATH`.  The reason `export` is required is that environment variables won't be *inherited* by subshells otherwise....

Comment: ...And there is NO means of making a change to an env variable instantaneously system wide; currently running shells are not affected if you change a shell config file, and only the *future* children subshells of a running shell are affected by `export`.  **This is on purpose** (which is probably why pkg-config uses such a system -- maybe not so obtuse!) and *environment* and environment variables are an important thing to understand, but that's a separate set of questions ;]

Comment: @goldilocks Unfortunately this sort of issue has been haunting me ever so often, here it is again : could you take a look at it pretty please!  http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13440911#13440911

Answer (score 1):

I'm working thru the same book, 21st Century C, and have the same problem. I found the solution that would let me compile this program in the GNU Docs at http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/gsl-ref.html.

> 2.3 Shared Libraries
>
> To run a program linked with the shared version of the library the
>   operating system must be able to locate the corresponding `.so` file at
>   runtime. If the library cannot be found, the following error will
>   occur:
>
> ```
> $ ./a.out  ./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: 
> libgsl.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such  file or
> directory
> ```
>
> To avoid this error, either modify the system dynamic linker
>   configuration or define the shell variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to include
>   the directory where the library is installed.
>
> For example, in the Bourne shell (`/bin/sh` or `/bin/bash`), the library
>   search path can be set with the following commands:
>
> ```
> $ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib $ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH $ ./example
> ```

Comment: The problem is usually face is `where is the sodded library installed!` Maybe I can search, sure, but usually where does it get installed?